# Use Python to Set Attributes in Maya Render Settings (Common Tab/Mental Ray)?

Tags: python, render, maya

I'm trying to set up predefined render setting in maya using python.  In the Render Settings window there are tabs, the first one called "Common" which includes things like "Color Management" and "File Output".

In the mental ray specific tabs, such as "Quality" I can easily change the setting with things like this

```
cmds.setAttr('miDefaultOptions.maxRefractionRays', 3)
cmds.setAttr('miDefaultOptions.maxShadowRayDepth', 2)
cmds.setAttr('miDefaultOptions.miSamplesMax', 2)
```

However, I can't do that for the "Common" tab.

Does anyone know if there's a way to set this up in Python? Specifically for Common>"Color Management".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use defaultRenderGlobals, defaultResolution and use listAttr to see the attributes. You need to set defaultRenderGlobals.outputColorProfle or inputColorProfile depending on your color profile.

Comment: You're the best (: Thank you

Comment: If you want to view the Attr of defaultRenderGlobals, defaultResolution in attribute editor. You can un-tick dag object in the outliner and pick these nodes.